# How do I enable personal roboport?

Tags: factorio

I know you have to have a personal roboport to enable it. I do, it's in my modular armor. It's with batteries and solarpanels (and it's daytime). And I have construction robots. But I can't click the "Enable personal roboport" button in the shortcut bar. Pressing Alt+H doesn't enable it either.

[image: Roboport button don't work (disabled)]

This might be helpful. I used the console code to...

> /unlock-shortcut-bar

...before I had researched robot technology. But for some reason the roboport button is disabled no matter how many times I click it.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your game with the modular armor's grid open (not cropped to that)?

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with the game but aren't you required to have batteries on your modular armor? Energy is drawn from that and the solar panels charge the battery from my understanding.

Comment: @JeffMercado The Roboports have an internal battery. So it isn't required. I've also tried it with batteries, reactor, shields, exoskeleton... everything I can think of. Interestingly, the batteries don't charge even with nothing else in there except energy generators...

Comment: I don't believe that's correct. Because if it had a charge, you'd see a bar indicating how full it is. And I distinctly recall that I tried to make use of a personal roboport in my own playthrough but couldn't until I added a battery.

Comment: @JeffMercado Cool. So I added a battery and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you made 2 modular armors, I see the problem: you haven't equipped the armor. It needs to be in the armor slot in the bottom left of the screen (next to where weapons and ammo go), not in your inventory.

Once you do, the button should be active immediately. However, it will take many minutes for the roboports to fully charge from the solar panels.

[image: Roboports displaying "low battery" symbol]

You may find them running out of power again as your robots recharge. Later you will be able to build the **power armor**, which has a 7×7 grid that can simultaneously fit roboports and the **portable fusion reactor**, which produces twice the power as the same area of solar panels (averaged over the day):